# Laravel - How to convert a derived table containing concatenation queries into Eloquent syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

How do I convert the following into Eloquent syntax? I know there is a derived table in there, so unsure what's the right syntax in Laravel for this?

```
    SELECT firstname
, CONCAT_WS
( ', '
, CASE WHEN years = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(years,' years') END
, CASE WHEN months = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(months, ' months') END
, CASE WHEN days = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(days, ' days') END
) lengthOfService
FROM
( SELECT firstname
, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425) years
, FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12) months
, CEILING((((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12)
- FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12))* 30) days
FROM users
) x
```

Comment: Eloquent is an ORM, it will translate physical relational tables into objects. I don't think it applies to derived tables. You can however add a scope in your users table to filter down to that derived table.

Comment: @apokryfos could I just wrap this into `DB::raw()` in theory?

Comment: Yes you can, but that's not really using Eloquent, that's just using the query builder.

Comment: Check out [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes) in case it helps (and in case you have a users model you can scope)

Comment: You could use hydrateRaw. It is not documented though: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrateRaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does provide hydrateRaw

First make a model class, I will use App\Models\MyHydratedUser

```
$query = "SELECT firstname, CONCAT_WS ( ', '
, CASE WHEN years = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(years,' years') END
, CASE WHEN months = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(months, ' months') END
, CASE WHEN days = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(days, ' days') END
) lengthOfService
FROM
( SELECT firstname
, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425) years
, FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12) months
, CEILING((((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12)
- FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12))* 30) days
FROM users
) x";

$users = App\Models\HydratedUser::hydrateRaw($query);
```

The $users variable will hold a Collection of HydratedUser models

Comment: thanks. This works well. I wish this method was documented in the official Laravel docs.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent does not provide such specific methods. You will need to use `DB::raw("...")` (but that's not a solution I guess), or `DB::select("SELECT ...");`

Answer (score 1):

**Without Eloquent with Query Builder**

Create sub query and using `DB::table` with `DB::raw` and `selectRaw()` method.

```
$subQuery = DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('firstname,
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425) years,
        FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 -
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12) months, 
        CEILING((((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - 
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12) - 
        FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425 - 
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startdate)/365.2425))* 12))* 30) days');

DB::table(DB::raw('('.$subQuery->toSql().') as tableName')
    ->selectRaw("firstname, CONCAT_WS(', ', 
        CASE WHEN years = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(years,' years') END, 
        CASE WHEN months = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(months, ' months') END, 
        CASE WHEN days = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(days, ' days') END) lengthOfService")
```