# general error: 2031 when uniting two queries (laravel datatables)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datatables

Those are the queries that form the collection to be pushed to the laravel datatables builder:

```
foreach (Session::get('trienios') as $trienio) {
    $oeTrienios = $oeTrienios->where('data_trienio', $trienio->trienio)->whereHas('curso', function ($query) use ($trienio) {
        $query->where('curso', $trienio->curso);
    });
}

$union = Trienio::with('curso')->whereHas('curso', function ($query) use ($coordinatedCourse) {
    $query->where('curso', $coordinatedCourse);
})->union($oeTrienios);


$trienios = \DB::table(\DB::raw("({$union->toSql()}) as x"))->select(['data_trienio']);
```

There is a tutorial on the official laravel-datatables site that "explains" how to work with united queries, however it is pretty vague and can't realistically explain anything, and besides, when I tried to add a code they had on the tutorial:

```
$trienios = \DB::table(\DB::raw("({$union->toSql()}) as x"))
```

It gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `data_trienio` from ((select * from `trienios` where exists (select * from `cursos` where `trienios`.`curso_id` = `cursos`.`id` and `curso` = ?)) union (select * from `trienios` where `data_trienio` = ? and exists (select * from `cursos` where `trienios`.`curso_id` = `cursos`.`id` and `curso` = ?) and `data_trienio` = ? and exists (select * from `cursos` where `trienios`.`curso_id` = `cursos`.`id` and `curso` = ?))) as x) count_row_table)
```

If I, however, attach the parameter `->get()` to the `->union($oeTrienios)`, it will work just fine, however, the collection will come unorderable on the datatable.

How do I solve this issue? Any help would be very welcome.

P.S - Link to the demo: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/union

Comment: Can you please mention link to the tutorial for uniting queries?

Comment: added to the post.

Answer (score 3):

The subquery `$union->toSql()` has only sql code without parameters and you need call `bindings`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44668479/3894654) and code will be:

```
$trienios = \DB::table(\DB::raw("({$union->toSql()}) as x"))
    ->select(['data_trienio'])
    ->mergeBindings($union);
```

Comment: throws this error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeBindings() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given.

Comment: I think `$union` should be `$union->getQuery()`.
Whatever, this one saved my life.